# How to find the average movie rating per year?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi so I am currently working on IMDB movie metadata dataframe that looks like this.

[image]

I need help finding average imdb rating per year. `imdb_score` per `title_year`.

Now I have counted the number of movies per year and dropped years with less than 10 movies for it to be relevant.

I did as follows

```
years = df['title_year'].value_counts()
years
```

and then

```
years2 = years[years >= 10]
years2
```

which resulted in

```
2009.0    260
2014.0    252
2006.0    239
2013.0    237
2010.0    230
2015.0    226
2011.0    225
2008.0    225
2012.0    221
2005.0    221
2004.0    214
2002.0    209
2007.0    204
2001.0    188
2000.0    171
2003.0    169
1999.0    168
1998.0    134
1997.0    118
2016.0    106
1996.0     99
1995.0     70
1994.0     54
1993.0     48
1992.0     34
1981.0     33
1989.0     33
1987.0     32
1991.0     31
1988.0     31
1984.0     31
1982.0     30
1990.0     30
1985.0     29
1986.0     26
1980.0     24
1983.0     22
1978.0     16
1977.0     16
1979.0     16
1970.0     12
1971.0     11
1968.0     11
1969.0     10
1964.0     10
1976.0     10
Name: title_year, dtype: int64
```

Now I am confused how do you find the average imdb rating per year because I would like to plot a graph afterwards. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```py
year_avg_score = df.loc[df['title_year'].isin(year2.index)].groupby('title_year')['imdb_score'].mean()
```

Step by step:

- `df.loc[df['title_year'].isin(year2.index)]` filters only the years with more than 10 movies, which you already computed.
- Then we groupby `title_year` and select the `imdb_score` column.
- Finally take the `imdb_score` average.

The resulting dataframe `year_avg_score` will have the year as index and the average score as column.

Comment: thank you so much brother Fbruzzesi. i have thought of using groupby but have not came up with the code yet thank you man